# How to get array of objects rather than array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

I am trying to do some mapping to come out with an array of objects.

Something like this:
[image]

But what I get from the following method is an array of arrays
[image]

```
this.service.getItems(this.id).pipe(
      switchMap(arr => {
        const userObservables = 
        arr.map(collects => this.afs.collection(`users`,
           (ref) => ref.where('someId', '==', collects.id)).valueChanges()
           .pipe(first())
        );
        return combineLatest(...userObservables)
            .pipe(
              map((...eusers) => {
                console.log(eusers[0]) //Should be array of objects
                arr.forEach((collect, index) => {
                  collect['username'] =  eusers[0][index]['displayName']['username'];
                  collect['first_name'] =  eusers[0][index]['displayName']['first_name'];
                  collect['last_name'] =  eusers[0][index]['displayName']['last_name'];
                  collect['avatar'] = eusers[0][index]['photoURL'];
              });
              console.log(arr)
              return arr;
            })
            );
      })
    )
    .subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));
```

How should I rewrite this to get the result(array of objects) I want?

Comment: Not an expert in rxjs, but maybe check out flatMap and try to substitute one of your map functions with flatMap

Comment: Okay, I will try that too.. @OleksandrFedotov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript**

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
>   does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

```
const array = [['1', '2'],['1'],['1','2','3']];
const newArray = [].concat.apply([], array);
```

Yet Lodash and Underscore are also great and cleaner for this behaviour:

**Lodash**

https://lodash.com/docs/#flatten

> Flattens array a single level deep.

```
_.flatten([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]);
// => [1, 2, [3, [4]], 5]
```

I've used **lodash** in an **Angular** project it is very simple to use.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'; 

let x = _.flatten(array.items);
```

*npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash*

**Underscore (JS)**

https://underscorejs.org/#flatten

> Flattens a nested array (the nesting can be to any depth). If you pass
>   shallow, the array will only be flattened a single level..

```
_.flatten([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
// => [1, 2, 3, 4];

_.flatten([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]], true);
// => [1, 2, 3, [[4]]];
```

*npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore*

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple for each style loop to push everything into a new array.

```
const input = [[1], [1], [1]];
const output = [];

input.forEach(arr => arr.forEach(elem => output.push(elem)));
```